# freeRTOS USING INTERRUPT AND TIMER ONESHOT IN A CODE MORSE PROJECT W ESP32

Tags: embedded, esp32, freertos

Eve guys,see, I took a shot developing this code. It's about a morse code encoder. I started from the beggining. This part that Ill show yall, I just copyied a documentation I took somewhere on internet.

I had a doubt and an request. I ask if u guy could (if it existed) an alternative way (more exploring hardware) for eencoding the morse code. And here goes the doubt, why the interrupt negative sensibility works better here? I found it very awkard when i changed it for POSEDGE, and realized that the proposal didnt work at all. ( the dashs rarely were captured).

Thats all. I Appreciate the help beforehand

```
#define BLINK_GPIO 21 //2
#define BUTTON_GPIO 0

#define ESP_INTR_FLAG_DEFAULT 0

#define DASH_PRD pdMS_TO_TICKS(200)
#define INTC_PRD pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000)

char morse[6];
uint8_t cnt = 0;

TimerHandle_t  xOneShotTimerDASH;// handle para o SoftTimer
BaseType_t xDASHTimerStarted, xINTCTimerStarted; // flag para checar timer

static void timerDASH_callback(void *pvParameters);
//static void timerINTC_callback(void *pvParameters);

static void IRAM_ATTR gpio_isr_handler(void* arg)
{
    xDASHTimerStarted = xTimerStart(xOneShotTimerDASH, 0);  
   // xINTCTimerStarted = xTimerStart(xOneShotTimerINTC, 0);   
}

void app_main(void)
{
    gpio_pad_select_gpio(BLINK_GPIO); // Configura o pino como IO
    gpio_set_direction(BLINK_GPIO,GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT); // Configura o IO como saida

    gpio_pad_select_gpio(BUTTON_GPIO); // Configura o pino como IO
    gpio_set_direction(BUTTON_GPIO,GPIO_MODE_INPUT); // Configura o IO como entrada

    gpio_set_intr_type(BUTTON_GPIO,GPIO_INTR_POSEDGE);
    gpio_intr_enable(BUTTON_GPIO);

    gpio_install_isr_service(ESP_INTR_FLAG_DEFAULT);
    gpio_isr_handler_add(BUTTON_GPIO, gpio_isr_handler, (void*) BUTTON_GPIO);
    ESP_LOGI("STARTUP","ISR Handler Instalado!!!");
    
    /* Create the one shot timer, storing the handle to the created timer in xOneShotTimer. */
    xOneShotTimerDASH = xTimerCreate("OneShot", DASH_PRD, pdFALSE, 0, timerDASH_callback);
    ESP_LOGI("STARTUP","DASH Timer Criado!!!");
    /* Create the one shot timer, storing the handle to the created timer in xOneShotTimer. */
    //xOneShotTimerINTC = xTimerCreate("OneShot", INTC_PRD, pdFALSE, 0, timerINTC_callback);
    ESP_LOGI("STARTUP","DASH Timer Criado!!!");
}

    static void timerDASH_callback(void *pvParameters)
    {
        if(gpio_get_level(BUTTON_GPIO))
        {
            ESP_LOGI("MORSE",".");
            morse[cnt++] = '.';
        }
        else
        {
            ESP_LOGI("MORSE","_");
            morse[cnt++] = '_';
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: The code is broken. You’d need to use xTimerStartFromISR. Note the FromISR tag for all FreeRTOS API functions usable in ISRs. Also I’d use e.g. task notifications to signal the interrupt event to a task waiting for it and process it. No idea why you’re using timers.

Comment: Okay, ill check it out.  See, just summing up the goal here. I press once the button an release it=dot written. I press and keep it for a while=dash written. The timer's propose is to allow in every callback routine (0.2s, after its counting began) to, once shot, veify if the button gpio continued HIGH (dash condition)

Comment: What if just signaling button up/down events to a task and let the task measure the time/duration e.g. simply using xTaskGetTickCount and evaluate the difference ?

Comment: @caio_alBR What kind of Hardware setup are using? Version of ESP32? What kind of "button" are using?   
Depending on this, you might have to consider jitter etc.

Comment: What kind of kernel object would I use to signal a task? I havent used anything similar to it before... If u could point some

Comment: @sebo1234 Hi there! Im using a project based on Custom Board. About which ESP it is, it's ESP WROVER Kit 32, i'm implementing the exercise through BUTTON 0 (boot button)